# Duplicate post problem

Tags: loop

I have two loops.

One that shows only one post, the other shows four. however i'm getting duplicate posts.

Loop one

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('showposts=1'); while ($my_query->have_posts()) : my_query->the_post(); $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>
```

Loop two

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('showposts=4'); while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Multiple_Loops_in_Action

Answer (score 0):

```
if( $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate ) continue;
```

This fixed it for me

Comment: Using `post__not_in` would probably provide more reliable results.

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Comment: The [Codex is your friend](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters). :)